# Rails doesn't show my image files. Route error [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I wrote:

```
$('.book_cover_here').html("<img src='http://bookworm.az/public" + $(this).data("cover") + "' />");
```

});

So, the whole URL is correct:

```
http://bookworm.az/public/uploads/covers/bookworm-2.png
```

But it doesn't show image file and prints Route error [GET]. I was added to config/application.rb the next line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

But it doesn't help too. How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

```
Started GET "/public/uploads/covers/bookworm-2.png" for 194.135.152.236 at 2015-01-03 07:33:32 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/uploads/covers/bookworm-2.png"):
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/share/ruby/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Please, post full error message. Also, please, post the corresponding route to this url.

Comment: @RubyRacer I add the full log

Comment: What if you just paste the full path manually to URL bar? For instance something like this:  `http://localhost:3000/system/media/image_videos/000/000/001/croppable/51647688d92ad407.png?1419981836`

Comment: Also if I am not mistaken, you don't have to include the public folder in the URL, so in your case it should be: `/uploads/covers/bookworm-2.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing the `/public/`  part from your URL?

When you launch the Rails application, you don't have to explicitly tell the application to search stuff from the `public` folder anymore. Rails will search for all assets in `public` folder by default during runtime.

So in your case:

```
('.book_cover_here').html("<img src='http://bookworm.az/" + $(this).data("cover") + "' />");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"<img src='http://bookworm.az/public" + $(this).data("cover") + "' />"
```

you open double quotes, then open single quotes, but then close double quotes and single quotes still open. is it correct?